# How to unpack type-defined types?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

For example

```
struct A { typedef int Type; }
struct B { typedef float Type; }

template<class... Ts>
struct C
{
    typedef tuple<Ts::Type...> TupleType; // comilation error: parameter pack 
                                          // expects a type template argument
};
```

How to unpack type-defined types?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need `typename`.

```
typedef tuple<typename Ts::Type...> TupleType;
```

Note that this has nothing to do with the fact that you're dealing with a parameter pack. You need `typename` here for the same reason as usual. In fact, if you had for instance

```
template<class T>
struct D {
    typedef vector<typename T::type> VectorType;
};
```

the `typename` would be necessary here too.